# Highcharts column range dataLabels reversed

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create an inverted column range chart with dataLabels on the insides of the bar but for some reason the labels are backwards (high on the left, low on the right).

```
var options = {
  chart: {
      type: 'columnrange',
      inverted: true,
      renderTo: 'container'
  },

  tooltip: {
      enabled: false
  },

  xAxis: {
      categories: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
  },

  yAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      dateTimeLabelFormats: {
          hour: '%l:%M'
      }

  },

  plotOptions: {
      columnrange: {
          dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              inside: true,
              color: 'white',
              formatter: function() {
                  return Highcharts.dateFormat('%l:%M', this.y);
              }
          }
      }
  },

  series: [{
      name: 'Series 1',
      data: [{
          "low": 1399536000000,
          "high": 1399550400000,
          "x": 0
      }, {
          "low": 1399536000000,
          "high": 1399550400000,
          "x": 1
      }, {
          "low": 1399536000000,
          "high": 1399550400000,
          "x": 2
      }, {
          "low": 1399536000000,
          "high": 1399550400000,
          "x": 3
      }, {
          "low": 1399536000000,
          "high": 1399550400000,
          "x": 4
      }, {
          "low": 1399536000000,
          "high": 1399550400000,
          "x": 5
      }, {
          "low": 1399536000000,
          "high": 1399550400000,
          "x": 6
      }]
  }]
};

$('#container').highcharts(options);
```

Here is a fiddle of the http://jsfiddle.net/slapner/S5m8z/6/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unforutnatley it is known bug reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2711)